# Adding item in a sharepoint list programmatically using visual studio basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to add an item to a SharePoint list using Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Basic Code (programmatically.)

I use Windows 8.1 - Visual Studio 2013 - and an Office365 SharePoint site.

Does anybody have a step-by-step solution for that?

Thanks